# SQL statement runs in SQL Server- Not in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 and have been told that I have all rights to create #temp tables.  I have done this before, but for some reason my sql in the new application always returns 0 rows.

I have the SQL connection string stored in my Application events as

```
Friend sqlConnProducts as String
```

I create a sql string and pass it to the SQLExecute Function

```
Private Function SQLExecute(ByVal sSQL As String) As DataTable
    Dim rtnTable As New DataTable()
    Dim sConn As New SqlConnection(My.Application.sqlConRecvInsp)
    Dim sCmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, sConn)
    Dim taAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sCmd)

    Try
        sConn.Open()
        sCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        taAdapter.Fill(rtnTable)
        sConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Failed at: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

    sConn.Dispose()
    sCmd.Dispose()

    Return rtnTable
End Function
```

I even have a debug.print(sql) in the sql creation phase.  When I run the output from the debug, I get about 7k records.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You do know what temp tables are, right?

Comment: For your kind information, you should enclose the `sConn.Dispose()` and `sCmd.Dispose()` into a `Finaly` clause so that they get disposed no matter whether your code throws. Furthermore, I recommend a good practice, not to say a best, that is to enclose the instantiation of your connection and the initialization of your command into `Using...End Using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that might light your path to your solution:

1. [SQL Team - Temporary Tables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables);
2. [Eliminate the Use of Temporary Tables For HUGE Performance Gains](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/derived_temp_tables_p1.aspx);
3. [Differences between SQL Server temporary tables and table variables](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1556);
4. [Should I use a #temp table or a @table variable?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html)

Finally, I doubt a temporary table i suitable for your needs here.

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This was helpful. I realized I could do this using a derived table. So I tried it. But the sql still doesn't run return anything in VS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. I was watching the value of my return table and it kept saying that the row count was 0. I added a datagrid and bound the DataTable to the dg.datasource and 7190 records are populated... So I'm guessing this is just an issue with Intelisence not Evaluating things properly, or my misunderstanding of how the intellisence works.

Comment: @GeekedAndTweaked: to quote the Bard, "All's well that ends well".  ('course, same dude commonly included the stage direction "Alarums and excursions"... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following regarding SQL Server temp tables - it may provide some guidance as to what's going on.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2006/11/03/17197.aspx

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the post. That is helpful. From what I can tell. I'm not losing scope before I run the select command though.